# How can I manipulate a string and eliminate the character * or #?

Tags: r

In R, how can I manipulate a string and eliminate the character * or #? For example in "ALL8606#057R0"  I try with `RFC_corr[5] = str_split(RFC[5],split= "#",fixed=true)`

Comment: This is a very common question - see "regular expressions", and in particular `?sub` and `?gsub`.

Answer (score 2):

As tospig suggested:

```
> sub("#", "", "ALL8606#057R0")
[1] "ALL8606057R0"
```

Edit for your comment below: to apply this to a vector you don't need a loop; you can just use the vector of interest when calling the function:

```
> x <- c("vect#or", "th-at#", "ha%s", "weir*d", "stu+ff")
> gsub("[-+%*#]", "", x)
[1] "vector" "that"   "has"    "weird"  "stuff"
```

```

Comment: `gsub("[*#]","",x)` will cover both `*` and `#` replacements.

Comment: Thanks!! I had problems with * and [, but with gsub function great...can I ask you something else XD : I want to make a loop with gsub..... For (i in 1 to lenght(RFC)){gsub("[*#-_" "[/%]","",RFC[i]}

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to verify this make a loop and visit for each char in that array when the "#" and "*" skip that while doing that make the copy of string that contains the string skip the  # and *.

```
int i=0;

string userstr="ALL8606#057R0";
char[] copystr=new char[userstr.Length()];
foreach(char s in userstr)
{
if(s!="#" || s!="*")
{
copystr[i]=s;
i++;
}
}
```

Hope this code will help you to resolve conflict.if you are getting the error in the userstr.Length so please put the hard coded value and try.
Bye and Happy Coding.

Comment: thanks...and if I only want alphanumeric?? and this in a loop?? I´m a dummy!!! =(:::::

Comment: Yes I know that is not in R but you can get the logic behind that ..If that could be done in R because I am a Asp.netMVC, C# developer.